# About the fix for the interference between Company mode and Yasnippet

Tags: emacs, plugins

[Emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CompanyMode) says:

> Company does interfere with
>   Yasnippet’s native behaviour. Here’s a
>   quick fix: 
>   http://gist.github.com/265010

The code is the following:

```
(define-key company-active-map "\t" 'company-yasnippet-or-completion)

(defun company-yasnippet-or-completion ()
  (interactive)
  (if (yas/expansion-at-point)
      (progn (company-abort)
             (yas/expand))
    (company-complete-common)))

(defun yas/expansion-at-point ()
  "Tested with v0.6.1. Extracted from `yas/expand-1'"
    (first (yas/current-key)))
```

I placed that code in my .emacs and the following message appeared:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `c:/Documents and Settings/Alex.AUTOINSTALL.001/Application Data/.emacs.elc':

Symbol's value as variable is void: company-active-map

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

Do I have to place the fix code inside a YASnippet's .el file? 
or in my .emacs (which throws me an error)?

Answer (score 6):

The snippet you mentioned doesn't work any more anyway.

Here's a snippet that you can use instead:

```
(defun company-yasnippet-or-completion ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((yas-fallback-behavior nil))
    (unless (yas-expand)
      (call-interactively #'company-complete-common))))
```

To make sure that this is called instead of `company-complete-common`, use

```
(add-hook 'company-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (substitute-key-definition 'company-complete-common
                             'company-yasnippet-or-completion
                             company-active-map)))
```

Background: This locally changes the value of `yas-fallback-behaviour`, which causes yas to call `company-complete-common` if no completion is found.

Comment: As the author of yasnippet, I can confirm this is a legal use of the API, whereas the previous code was not.

Comment: isn't `(apply 'company-complete-common nil)` just a verbose way of saying `(company-complete-common)`? Or is it supposed to be `(quote (apply company-complete-common))`?

Comment: @npostavs: You're right, there was a missing quote there. I took that opportunity to simplify the snippet.

Answer (score -3):

That sounds like a problem with the load-path. The symbol value being void means that emacs can't find a definition for it - most likely because the file containing its definition has not been loaded yet.

You may try adding something like this in your .emacs (before the error-causing code):

```
;; where ~/.emacs.d/ is the path to a directory containing
;; additional library code you want emacs to load
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")
```

Comment: That would not be the problem since he isnt specifically loading anything when accessing the map. The problem there is that he hasnt loaded company-mode at that point.